# Error inflating class for android 2.3

Tags: android, crash, material-design

I am developing an application using the following [library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) for material 
design

Unfortunately, my app crashes when it runs on android 2.3 (gingerbread) emulator

Note that i also use AppCompat Library.

So that's what emulator shows me (i hide the package name)
[image]

And **line 30** is:

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.Slider
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1E88E5"
                materialdesign:max="50"
                materialdesign:min="0"
                materialdesign:showNumberIndicator="true"/>
```

Comment: You should report this bug: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues But this library is not that active anymore, lots of pending work, and lots of alternatives (including Android Design library).

Comment: thanks dude i really appreciate your answer